# iOS Animation Block: Content of Image Flickers while Rotating

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, block, uiviewanimation

I am trying to rotate an image (UIImageView) within an Animation Block. The image contains fine lines horizontally (like the lines within an image of a notepad, for instance). But while being rotated the lines within the image flickers / moving up and down wildly as if they were being scrolled up and down like a UITableView. The edges of the image are not jagged as I am using a transparent border. I have searched for days on google but to no avail.

It seems to me that this must have occurred to someone already, but I have not been able to find any answers even searching for answers that are not just iOS specific.

------------ UPDATE --------------

Not just rotation, even moving the image around the screen without rotation with the following piece of code would cause wild flickering on the lines within the image itself.

```
UIImageView *notepad = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect) {{0, 0}, 245, 256}];
notepad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notepad.png"];
```

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{notepad.center = (CGPoint){115.0f, 845.0f};}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                                          delay:0.0
                                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                     animations:^{
                                  notepad.center = (CGPoint) {423.0f, 23.0f};}
                                     completion:nil];
          }];

An image such as this here:  http://www.wpclipart.com/education/supplies/paper/notepad_page.png.html

Thanks.

Comment: Please could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Could you post example code?

Comment: You must be animating within another view that is doing something weird. What is the imageView's parent view hierarchy?